# Looking to use a table to populate a combo box but populate the target table with the description instead of the record ID

Tags: ms-access

I am working on a database for a journal, and have a field called Keyword.  At first I made the Keyword a free form text field.  It did not take long for the list of keywords to grow making it unusable as a keyword field.  What I ended  up doing was using a combo box with the list being populated within the combo box properties.

Now what I am looking to do is to perform a query where the user is prompted for their choice of keywords, which resides only within the combo box on the form.

Any suggestions?

I tried to make an additional table called Keywords, and then used the combo box configuration wizard but directing it to populate the keyword field in the target table with the keyword description.  This did not work.

Comment: Query prompt for choice of keywords won't work. Question is too broad, lacks code for analysis. "Did not work" is not helpful - what happens? Error message, wrong result, nothing? Provide sample data as text table.

Comment: most likely you should start by filtering a form with one to many unbound comboboxes.  See here for a start: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=uq3cgaHF6fc

Answer (score 0):

It can be done but you will need to do it with some VBA code. You might want to consider using a multiselect Listbox in a small popup modal form. Alternatively, just provide the Listbox on your main form with a 'Go' button. When the user clicks the Go button after selecting all their keywords, your background code in the button OnClick event can read through all the selected keywords and build a filter list. This list can then be applied to the Filter property of your form (don't forget to set the FilterOn property to True. For example:

```
fldKeyword IN ('Keyword1','Keyword4','Keyword7')
```